# Link command to another command

Tags: command-line, command, alias

I want to link the `ssh` command to `autossh` command, so for example when I type `ssh user@example.com` it will execute `autossh user@example.com`.

I was tried `ln -s autossh ssh` but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command you are looking for is `alias`.

The general syntax for the `alias` command varies somewhat according to the shell. In the case of the `bash` shell (or any `sh`-like shell) it is

```
alias [-p] [name="value"]
```

So it seems you want:

```
alias ssh="autossh"
```

Comment: There is no need for the space (and it means alias the next word also).

Comment: It was a typo I'm on cellphone